# Text Replacement With RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using Sublime Text to write some Javascript and need to do a simple text replacement in the editor in order to set code up. I can do it manually but I figured there must be a way to have the replacement occur automatically with RegEx. I've used RegEx a bunch before but have never used it to grab data from one part of the code to reference and edit another part of the code. For example, I have this:

```
var example_1 = 836;
var example_2 = 837;
var example_3 = 838;
var example_4 = 846;
```

And then I have this:

```
SELECT_122=836
SELECT_143=837
SELECT_144=838
SELECT_145=846
```

I want these to use the corresponding values and format them like this:

```
SELECT_122: example_1,
SELECT_143: example_2,
SELECT_144: example_3,
SELECT_145: example_4
```

Note that I'm updating the equal signs to colons with spaces so I figured doing all these changes could be done with some sort of search and replace. I have a large amount of these so I figured it would be best to learn how to do this if it's possible.

Comment: I say it'd be a better idea to sort those values into an array, then use an array search function to create your desired output

Comment: Hmm, that's a great idea but I'm looking specifically for a way to do it through a text editor. I may end up using that idea anyhow but am curious if anyone knows of a way to do it (or if it's even possible to do) in a text editor like Sublime Text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have SublimeText, but you said in a comment that you want to do it through a text editor. Here is what works for me in EditPad Pro, it may work in Sublime.

**Search:**

```
(?s)(var (example_\d++) = (\d++).*?SELECT_\d++)=\3
```

**Replace:**

```
\1: \2,
```

Then I click "Replace". This will replace the first instance (SELECT_122=836) with "SELECT_122: example_1,"

Then I click "Replace Next" multiple times, and the SELECT_ strings are left looking like this:

```
SELECT_122: example_1,
SELECT_143: example_2,
SELECT_144: example_3,
SELECT_145: example_4,
```

Is this what you want?

Hope the regex and replacement string at least get you started. :)